# Swagger editor doesn't offer relevant code completion

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

When I use swagger editor (online or local) sometimes it offers code completion of the relevant level and often it starts offering code completion of the root level: definitions, swagger, info, paths, etc. while my cursor is not at the root level, for example when I'm entering properties. There are also no indications that tell that there is something wrong with the document. I cannot see the pattern to find out when this happens, it just happens and it makes the editor very difficult to use as I have to type almost everything.

I wish I could provide more details but for now this problem happens randomly. Does anyone know what can cause this behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: You should probably file an issue in the [Swagger Editor's GitHub repo](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues) instead of asking here.

Comment: You are right, I don't remember why I posted this question here instead of there. Thanks